# HttpContext.Current.Session gets cleared on routing in Azure Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, session-state

```
 public static WebUser LoggedUser
        {
            get
            {
                WebUser sessionValue = null;
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"] != null)
                {
                    sessionValue = (WebUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"];
                }
                return sessionValue;
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"] = value;
            }
        }
```

HttpContext.Current.Session gets cleared on routing in Azure Server, the same works fine in IIS server but why not in Azure??

Please help me in persisting session value

Answer (score 1):

> HttpContext.Current.Session gets cleared on routing in Azure Server, the same works fine in IIS server but why not in Azure??

I assume that you use the multiple instances Azure WebApp. If it is that case, we could get the answer from the azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching). Please have a try use external session state provider (either the **Redis Cache Service** or a **SQL Server session state provider**).

> If your ASP.NET web app uses session state, you will need to configure an external session state provider (either the **Redis Cache Service** or a **SQL Server session state provider**). If you use session state, and don't use an external provider, you will be limited to **one instance** of your web app.

Comment: It was local adminstrator firewall which was causing the problem, now its working fine, Thank yu :)